# Permutation predicate in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic

I have written the following in Prolog (I am using version 7.4.0-rc1), trying to define a predicate `insertPermutation/2` which is true if and only if both arguments are lists, one a permutation of the other.

```
delete(X,[X|T],T). % Base case, element equals head.
delete(X,[A|B],[A|C]) :- delete(X,B,C). % And/or repeat for the tail.

insert(X,Y,Z) :- delete(X,Z,Y). % Inserting is deletion in reverse.

insertPermutation([],[]). % Base case.
insertPermutation([H|T],P) :- insertPermutation(Q,T), insert(H,Q,P). % P permutation of T, H inserted.
```

I have already been made aware that delete is not a good name for the above helper predicate. We are required to write these predicates, and we cannot use the built-in predicates. This is why I wrote the above code in this way, and I chose the name I did (because I first wrote it to delete an element). It is true if and only if the third argument is a list, equal to the list in the second argument with the first instance of the first argument removed.

The insertPermutation predicate recursively tests if P equals a permutation of the tail of the first list, with the head added in any position in the permutation. This way it works to the base case of both being empty lists.

However, the permutation predicate does not behave the way I want it to. For instance, to the query

```
?- insertPermutation([1,2,2],[1,2,3]).
```

Prolog does not return false, but freezes. To the query

```
?- insertPermutation(X,[a,b,c]).
```

Prolog responds with

```
X = [a, b, c] ;
X = [b, a, c] ;
X = [c, a, b] ;
X = [a, c, b] ;
X = [b, c, a] ;
X = [c, b, a] ;
```

after which it freezes again. I see these problems are related, but not how. Can someone point out what case I am missing?

Edit: Two things, this is homework, and I need to solve this problem using an insert predicate. I wrote this one.

Comment: Why don't you look at how Prolog does it? See [permutation/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=permutation/2) The idea is to convert both versions to a [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form)  then compare. If they have the same canonical form then they can be a permutation of each other or identical to each other.

Comment: For this problem I am required to use a function that inserts an element, that is why! I have already written an alternative definition that does work, but cannot get it to work using the insert predicate.

Comment: You should say that in the question and if it is homework say so.

Comment: I wasn't aware, I've added it.

Comment: At the end you say `I need to solve this problem using this insert predicate` and at the start you say `I have written the following in Prolog`. Do you have to use an insert predicate? Did the teacher give you any code? You will get much better answers and faster if you make it easy for us. It is not uncommon for me to spend an hour crafting a question and because I do I often get the help I need. You are the one who should be doing most of the work for your question, we should only have to read it, quickly understand it and then give an answer. :)

Comment: You are right, I've added this as well. I need to use an insert predicate, and this is the one I've written. I was not provided with any code, just a few test cases. I thought my question included all details, thanks for pointing this one out.

Comment: For `permutation([1,2,2],[1,2,3]).` with your posted code using SWI-Prolog, I get `?- permutation([1,2,2],[1,2,3]).
false.` You say `Prolog does not return false, but freezes.` Which Prolog are you using?

Comment: Copy-pasted: _SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.4.0-rc1)_. Will add this as well. I am just going to ask up front, is there any more I should add to the question? I hadn't even considered Prolog had different versions!

Comment: just a side note, in your `delete/2`'s second clause, in `% Else, repeat for the tail.`, it is not "else,", but **"and, possibly, also"**. Both clauses could be working, e.g. with `delete(1, [1,2,1,3], R)`.

Comment: @WillNess Changed it!

Comment: First thing you should do is to rename your predicates so that they are not the same name as the standards ones. e.g. change `permutation` to `my_permutation`, etc. Then you should use either `trace` or `gtrace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change the last line

```
% P permutation of T, H inserted.
insertPermutation([H|T],P) :- 
    insertPermutation(Q,T), 
    insert(H,Q,P).

% P permutation of T, H inserted.
insertPermutation(P,[H|T]) :- 
    insertPermutation(Q,T), 
    insert(H,Q,P).
```

The use cases only needed to check if the first element is a permutation of the latter, not the other way around (or vice versa). Anti-climatic, but the answer to my problem.

Comment: Y U no use tail recursion?